# I am not getting push notification from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I enabled Firebase Messaging Service.I did everything right but at the end Notification is not coming on mobile phone. I tried the suggestion and help posted in other similar question ut none helped.

MessagingService.java

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

}

public void showNotification(String message){
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,new Intent(this,MainActivity.class),0);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("**")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notification);
}
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="*****">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="******.MessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/icon" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

</application>
```

By the way I am using Notification builder which is deprecated. Is it have something to do with this? Please help me to figure out.

Comment: Did you check if the remote message is received?

Comment: How can I do that? By checking in Log Cat?

Comment: you can introduce breakpoints and run the app in debug mode.

Comment: While making the notification,firebase showsThis campaign targets 0 app user(s) (0% of potential users. Why?

Comment: Are you sending notification by topic?

Comment: No, I am sending to all, directly to app.

Comment: Try putting `Log.d("Notif", remoteMessage.toString())` in `onMessageRecieved()` and check if it is recieved.